# Excel 'Jump Menus' where dropdown options change per other selections

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Is it possible to create 'jump menus' in Excel?

The same principle as those used on a website. Depending on option you choose, the next menu changes. Please see example below

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

With thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the following set-up.

On some sheet set-up some named ranges, e.g. a vendor list (`VendorList`) and some other lists with productions e.g. `AppleList` and `MSList`:

[image]

And e.g. a list of products:

[image]

On another sheet, you can set-up two cells with data validations. Set one to be `VendorList` and the other defaulting to e.g. `AppleList`:
[image]

And the other cells validation:
[image]

Then, in the `Worksheet` code module, put in this code for the `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo CleanUp

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Selection1")) Is Nothing Then
        'suspend events
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'remove existing validation
        Range("Selection2").Validation.Delete
        'add new validation to Selection2
        Select Case Range("Selection1").Value
            Case "Apple"
                    Range("Selection2").Validation.Add _
                        Type:=xlValidateList, _
                        Formula1:="=AppleList"
            Case "Microsoft"
                    Range("Selection2").Validation.Add _
                        Type:=xlValidateList, _
                        Formula1:="=MSList"
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select

    End If

CleanUp:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Note the code suspends `EnableEvents` as you are changing `Range` values as part of the event handler.

Comment: No need for vba,   you can use  =INDIRECT() to create a reference to the second list based on the first list selection